# HTML5 Have left aligned text and right aligned text in same line within paragraph

Tags: css, html, text, alignment

I want to have "This is a test" left aligned and "[Rare photograph]" right aligned but still be on the same line.

I'm a newbie at HTML5, so a simple explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks! :)

```
<p style = "margin-left:75px;max-width:750px;"><br/>
        This is a test.
        [Rare photograph]


</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that without an additional tag, but what you can do is inject a `<span>` tag **within** a `<p>` tag, and give each `<span>` a respective `float: left` and `float: right`:

```html
<p style="margin-left: 75px; max-width: 750px;">
  <span style="float: left">This is a test.</span>
  <span style="float: right">[Rare photograph]</span>
</p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I am trying to do this exact same thing and the text in the `span` tag does not align to the right.

Comment: @filtfilt -- Make sure that the parent element has `display: block` (which is the default for `<p>` tags). Displays such as `flex`, `grid`, `inline-block` and `table` all won't work with `float`. Also ensure that your styles aren't getting overridden by other styles with greater [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) :)

Comment: Basically I have: `<p> some text, <span style="float:right">some other <strong> text</strong></span><br> some text<br> etc <br></p>`. So I do have the parent with a block display, yet the float right is not doing much.

Comment: @filtfilt -- If that is the **only** code you have, then your `<span>` will *indeed* float to the right. Some of your other code is interfering. Considering you have a different (although similar) problem, you really should [**ask a new question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this, ensuring that you provide **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it helps, feel free to link to this question in the new one :)

Comment: Well, it is in a `<div class="class1"> where `class1` has `padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;` and `line-height: 110%;` set. The body has `font-weight: 200;`,`font-size:14px;` and `font-family` set, but that should not interfere with the float.